# Socket.io with Swift is not handshaking

Tags: node.js, swift, websocket, swiftui, socket.io-1.0

I'm trying to integrate iOS app with Node.js WebSocket Server.
I'm using SwiftUI for the iOS and socket.io for both server and client.

But it when I am trying to connect the iOS app with the server,
It seems to not connect with the server.

I tested if the server is running by connecting a React app to the Node.js server
and the connection is working just fine with the browser.

I've checked the swift logs and It seems trying to handshake with the server but,
it starts long polling so I'm guessing the handshaking process has some kinda issue.

I'm console logging "new connection" as a string in Node.js server if there is a new connection and, it's working fine for React but not Swift.

But I'm not trying anything advance so I can't find out what is wrong.

Can someone help me out pls?

```
import SwiftUI
import SocketIO

final class Service: ObservableObject {
    private var manager = SocketManager(socketURL:URL(string: "http://localhost:5000")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    
    init() {
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket
        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect)  { (data,act) in
            print("Connected")
        }
        socket.connect()
    }
}

struct SocketIO: View {
    @ObservedObject var service = Service()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, Web socket!")
    }
}
```

This is the log I'm getting from SocketIO-client-swift

> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.033132+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG
> SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connect 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.033663+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketIOClient{/}:
> Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2] 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.033811+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining
> namespace / 2020-12-18 13:08:24.033930+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG
> SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open.
> Connecting 2020-12-18 13:08:24.034033+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG
> SocketManager: Adding engine 2020-12-18 13:08:24.035507+0900
> Tests[4397:171427] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server:
> http://localhost:5000 2020-12-18 13:08:24.035608+0900
> Tests[4397:171427] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.038113+0900 Tests[4397:171427] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing
> polling GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.125554+0900 Tests[4397:171431] []
> nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.166652+0900 Tests[4397:171427] LOG
> SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.166801+0900 Tests[4397:171427] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got
> poll message:
> 0{"sid":"97Fb8N3Ub5ZuRlfHAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.168076+0900 Tests[4397:171427] LOG SocketEngine:
> Got message:
> 0{"sid":"97Fb8N3Ub5ZuRlfHAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.171813+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG
> SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: ping with data: [] 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.171845+0900 Tests[4397:171427] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing
> polling GET
> http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=97Fb8N3Ub5ZuRlfHAAAA
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.172148+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketManager:
> Engine opened Connect 2020-12-18 13:08:24.172267+0900
> Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Socket connected 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.172485+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketIOClient{/}:
> Handling event: statusChange with data: [connected, 3] 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.172704+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketIOClient{/}:
> Handling event: connect with data: ["/"] Connected 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.174125+0900 Tests[4397:171427] LOG SocketEngine: Writing
> poll:  has data: false 2020-12-18 13:08:24.174260+0900
> Tests[4397:171427] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.174607+0900 Tests[4397:171427] LOG
> SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.175188+0900 Tests[4397:171427] LOG SocketEnginePolling:
> POSTing 2020-12-18 13:08:24.175708+0900 Tests[4397:171427] LOG
> SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling POST
> http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=97Fb8N3Ub5ZuRlfHAAAA
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.181566+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG
> SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: websocketUpgrade with data:
> [["upgrade": "websocket", "connection": "Upgrade",
> "sec-websocket-accept": "DK4ZA/luKjOL11P+2vm4APQNE5I="]] 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.181780+0900 Tests[4397:171429] LOG SocketEngineWebSocket:
> Sending ws: probe as type: 2 2020-12-18 13:08:24.183557+0900
> Tests[4397:171431] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.183723+0900 Tests[4397:171431] LOG
> SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET
> http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=97Fb8N3Ub5ZuRlfHAAAA
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.184529+0900 Tests[4397:171427] LOG SocketEngine:
> Flushing probe wait 2020-12-18 13:08:24.186620+0900 Tests[4397:171428]
> ERROR SocketEnginePolling: Error during long poll request 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.186736+0900 Tests[4397:171428] ERROR SocketEngine: Error
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.186892+0900 Tests[4397:171225] ERROR
> SocketManager: Error 2020-12-18 13:08:24.186907+0900
> Tests[4397:171428] LOG SocketEngine: Engine is being closed.
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.187029+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG
> SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: error with data: ["Error"]
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.187306+0900 Tests[4397:171428] LOG
> SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:1 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.187548+0900 Tests[4397:171428] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing
> polling POST
> http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=97Fb8N3Ub5ZuRlfHAAAA
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.188161+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketManager:
> Starting reconnect 2020-12-18 13:08:24.188342+0900 Tests[4397:171225]
> LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data:
> [connecting, 2] 2020-12-18 13:08:24.188558+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG
> SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: reconnect with data: ["Error"]
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.188729+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketManager:
> Trying to reconnect 2020-12-18 13:08:24.188830+0900 Tests[4397:171225]
> LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: reconnectAttempt with data:
> [-1] 2020-12-18 13:08:24.189043+0900 Tests[4397:171429] LOG
> SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://localhost:5000
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.189113+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketManager:
> Scheduling reconnect in 15.068159317825785s 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.189439+0900 Tests[4397:171429] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.189732+0900 Tests[4397:171429] LOG
> SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET
> http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.197564+0900 Tests[4397:171432] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got
> polling response 2020-12-18 13:08:24.197690+0900 Tests[4397:171432]
> LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message:
> 0{"sid":"7RPKclRosgovPKY5AAAB","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.197839+0900 Tests[4397:171432] LOG SocketEngine:
> Got message:
> 0{"sid":"7RPKclRosgovPKY5AAAB","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.198569+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG
> SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: ping with data: [] 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.198587+0900 Tests[4397:171432] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing
> polling GET
> http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=7RPKclRosgovPKY5AAAB
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.198671+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketManager:
> Engine opened Connect 2020-12-18 13:08:24.198848+0900
> Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Socket connected 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.199022+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketIOClient{/}:
> Handling event: statusChange with data: [connected, 3] 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.199197+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG SocketIOClient{/}:
> Handling event: connect with data: ["/"] Connected 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.199445+0900 Tests[4397:171432] LOG SocketEngine: Writing
> poll:  has data: false 2020-12-18 13:08:24.199714+0900
> Tests[4397:171432] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.199973+0900 Tests[4397:171432] LOG
> SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.200257+0900 Tests[4397:171432] LOG SocketEnginePolling:
> POSTing 2020-12-18 13:08:24.200524+0900 Tests[4397:171432] LOG
> SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling POST
> http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&sid=7RPKclRosgovPKY5AAAB
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.205180+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG
> SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: websocketUpgrade with data:
> [["upgrade": "websocket", "connection": "Upgrade",
> "sec-websocket-accept": "e5m4DoLk6GlrzUzZSHtQ/n0gXl0="]] 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.205309+0900 Tests[4397:171429] LOG SocketEngineWebSocket:
> Sending ws: probe as type: 2 2020-12-18 13:08:24.207171+0900
> Tests[4397:171429] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 3probe 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.207420+0900 Tests[4397:171429] LOG SocketEngine: Received
> probe response, should upgrade to WebSockets 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.207622+0900 Tests[4397:171429] LOG SocketEngine: Upgrading
> transport to WebSockets 2020-12-18 13:08:24.209704+0900
> Tests[4397:171429] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 6
> 2020-12-18 13:08:24.210114+0900 Tests[4397:171225] LOG
> SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: pong with data: [] 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.210826+0900 Tests[4397:171431] LOG SocketEngine: Flushing
> probe wait 2020-12-18 13:08:24.211131+0900 Tests[4397:171431] LOG
> SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.211279+0900 Tests[4397:171431] LOG SocketEngine: Switching to
> WebSockets 2020-12-18 13:08:24.211500+0900 Tests[4397:171431] LOG
> SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws:  as type: 5 2020-12-18
> 13:08:24.211974+0900 Tests[4397:171431] LOG SocketEngine: Flushing
> probe wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be related to security.
Typically ios apps expect connections using https. To allow http connections, in your
info.plist add this (temporary security fix):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>

 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: thank you for the comment but, I have already edit the info.plist. And I tested if the simulator can connect the server by returning HTML code from the same node.js server by router and I can see it from a UIRepresentable WebView, so I assume that It's not about the connection itself. But thanks for the answer anyway;)

Comment: you could try config: [.forceWebsockets(true), .log(true)])

Comment: I passed .forceWebsockets(true) and it seems the logs have changed but still not working as expected the print statement is firing but it keeps coming up. Seems that it's trying to connect WebSocket not polling but still keeps on failing. And the server-side seems to not recognize the connection.

Comment: I've tried other frameworks, such as "Apple Network->NWConnection" and "WebSocket" at: https://github.com/shareup/websocket-apple 
and both work well in my test. But I could not make "SocketIO" connect to "wss://echo.websocket.org" for example.

The "SocketIO" FAQ says; "This library is NOT a WebSockets library."
There seems to be a lot of issues with "SocketIO", maybe there is something broken.

Comment: Oh is it? thanks for the information! I was still struggling to use SocketIO so it really helped me! If it is possible I wanted to use the same party's framework but I guess what work is the best. Thanks a lot :)